# Как уменьшить перспективу камеры THREE.PerspectiveCamera

Tags: three.js

Как на движке *THREE.JS* изменить перспективу в камере (*PerspectiveCamera*), чтобы в даль уходящие параллельные линии не так быстро сужались?

Comment: Есть подробная документация по Three.js. Если интересует именно PerspectiveCamera, то вот ссылка http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Cameras/PerspectiveCamera.

Answer (score 1):

Порегулируйте угол обзора (Field of View - FOV)

```
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( fov, width / height, 1, 1000 );
```